# Settings messed up in Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, undo

I updated the PHP version to 4.5 in my Typo3 Webspace and now this message is showing:
This installation was just upgraded to TYPO3 4.5. In this version, some default settings have changed. You can continue to use your settings by specifying the former default values in localconf.php. Please proceed to the Update Wizard in the TYPO3 Install Tool to update your configuration.

I cant login to my frontend or anything.. is there a way to undo this?

Comment: i wonder if you did "Please proceed to the Update Wizard in the TYPO3 Install Tool to update your configuration."?

Comment: Yes it was the wirzard in my Typo3 frontend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either downgrade again, or you can go to the install tool at `http://example.com/typo3/install/` and run all the upgrade wizards.

To downgrade, you just have to put the `typo3` and `t3lib` folder from the old source back in place. Please note that `TYPO3 4.5 LTS` is the oldest version still supported with bugfixes and `TYPO3 4.4` is the oldest version still supported with security fixes (bug not bugfixes). Have a look at this [table](https://typo3.org/download/packages/#c7210).

Comment: Ah OK, I just tried it out. The Install Tool is locked
To enable the Install Tool, the file ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL must be created. 
•In the typo3conf/ folder, create a file named ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL. The file name is case sensitive, but the file itself can simply be an empty file. 
•Alternatively, in the Backend, go to User tools > User settings and let TYPO3 create this file for you. When you're finished, you can also visit User tools > User settings and delete the file from there. What would be the exact path to the /typo3conf ? http://example.com/typo3/typo3conf ?

Comment: `examples.com/typo3conf/ ` so it must be `/path/to/website/typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL`. Once you created teh file, the install will unlock for one hour and you can login. In case you forgot your `Install Tool` password, the login will tell you what to do once you enter any password (mainly copying the encrypted form of the entered password into `localconf.php` located in the very same `typo3conf/` directory).

Comment: examples.com/typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL tells me that an 404 Error message?

Comment: Yes, you have to *create* the file in the filesystem. The file may be empty and must not have any file extension. This file will be removed if it is older than one hour.